# What is the reason behind null checks in method reference expression evaluation?

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, method-reference

There are a bunch of questions where people have realized that creating a method reference with an expression that evaluates to a `null` value will result in a `NullPointerException`. As an example:

```
String s = null;
Supplier<char[]> fun = s::toCharArray;
```

This is due to the following paragraph in the java specification:

> First, if the method reference expression begins with an ExpressionName or a Primary, this subexpression is evaluated. If the subexpression evaluates to null, a NullPointerException is raised, and the method reference expression completes abruptly. If the subexpression completes abruptly, the method reference expression completes abruptly for the same reason.

Now my question is, does anyone happen to know what the reason behind this (based on the many confused questions) counterintuitive specification was/is?

The only thing that comes to my mind is that in the following case it is hard to accurately report the error of the `NullPointerException` if it happens during the evaluation of the `Supplier`:

```
public static char[] callback(Supplier<char[]> supplier) {
    return supplier.get();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = null;
    callback(s::toCharArray);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything counterintuitive in getting a NPE when trying to work with a null reference.

Comment: I guess the question should actually be "why is it not the same behavior for a lambda expression?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason here is the fact that when you are creating non static method reference, it must have access to `this`. When you are trying to create reference to null object, there is no `this` anywhere, that is why it should fail on this step, instead of failing somewhere further in the code when it is used for the first time.

Imagine in one place you get the object, save it's method reference somewhere, and than use it in completely different part of code. You'll get an NPE not in the place where the error was made, but many lines of code away.

Comment: Agreed about the error reporting that could be confusing, but - maybe thats my C++ history talking - capturing a `null` for a `this` reference to me does not immediately seem to be a problem until to you try to make use of it.

Comment: I guess assuming that method reference contains valid `this` in 100% of cases allows to do some hardcore JIT optimizations

Comment: @YanickSalzmann there are two opposing design approaches, the “fine until you try to use it” approach you mentioned and the “fail fast, to try to spot errors as soon as possible” approach. The designers of the newer language features and the related APIs clearly favor the latter style. You’ll notice when you try a `forEach(null)` on an empty collection. Most implementation will deliberately check the consumer for `null` and throw, even if they wouldn’t need to touch it otherwise. Note that the behavior of method references is on par with the older `expression.new InnerClass()` language feature

Answer (score 2):

Because the Java compiler is not a linter/logic checker.
Nothing in Java prevents you to trigger a NPE by dereferencing `null`.
For example Java doesn't prevent you from doing :

```
String s = null;
s.toString();
```

That is right before Java 8 and that is right still today for method references.

The paragraph you quote details simply how **at runtime** the JVM handles this point for method references that is that if a part of the method reference evaluation fails, the whole evaluation fails.

Note that in your actual example your IDE will probably emit a warning because the scope of the potential bug is very tight.